# How can I run a macro whenever I enter a new slide?

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like to have a simple macro run whenever I enter a new slide, whether I got there by normal click-to-advance or by following a link within the slideshow.  Is this possible?  I've searched for some kind of "page" or "slide" object upon which I could add an "enter" or "load" action, but if it exists I have not found it yet.

The goal is to set a "previous slide" global var, which is used to implement a Back button.  Note that this button returns the user to the last slide he or she was on, not necessarily the previous slide in order.  That is, on slide #4 I click a link to slide #101 in the appendix, then click Back and I go back to #4, not #100.  This works fine, I just need to know which slide I was at.

As a workaround, I'm adding an invisible object to the slide master, with a mouse-over action to call this macro.  This should work, but it seems ugly.

Is there a better way?  Thank you!

---

Here's the code which worked:

```
 Public PreviousSlideIndex As Long
 Public CurrentSlideIndex As Long

 Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Window As SlideShowWindow)
      PreviousSlideIndex = CurrentSlideIndex
      CurrentSlideIndex = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
 End Sub

 Sub ReturnToPreviousSlide()
      ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GoToSlide PreviousSlideIndex
 End Sub
```

I set `ReturnToPreviousSlide` to the OnClick action for my Back button, and all's good.

You could make this a little sophisticated with a stack of previous pages, allowing users to futz around for a few slides and still return from whence they came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `SlideShowNextSlide` event, as documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745863.aspx:

> Occurs immediately before the transition to the next slide. For the
>   first slide, occurs immediately after the SlideShowBegin event.

An example is included at the MSDN link.

Per http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/run_macro_at_slide.html ("Run VBA macro at a particular slide"), there is also a `OnSlideShowPageChange` event, though I've not been able to find any official documentation for this on MDSN.  However, per http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html:

> Occurs after showing the new slide.
>
> This is an auto-macro and does not require any object to be declared.
>   It is fired even when the presentation that hosts these event handlers
>   is not in slide show mode.

Comment: The `OnSlideShowPageChange` event was perfect, with minimal overhead.  Thanks!